# How increase classes in HTB?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, network-share, traffic

I am trying to setup a traffic shaping by HTB and tc. I have 70,000 users and I want to control the bandwidth of each user, so I create 70000 classes, and assign each ip address to a class by ip table.

Note that I want control each user individual, and I understand to do it. I must create an individual class for each user, but there is a problem to create classes. It doesn't let me to create more than 9999 classid. How can I solve this problem? Is there any other better way to setup this scenario?

Comment: Ask yourself whether you really have 70000 distinct configuration scenarios. I mean, you're not going to differentiate per-user bandwidth by the kilobit, right? Just define the number of distinct use cases you have (1 Mbps, 5 Mbps, 10 Mbps, 50 Mbps etc.) and then reassign classes to users when you want to change it

Comment: i want to control maximum and minimum rate so i create 70000 classes . if create some classes and assign ip addreess to classes the bandwidth is shared between users in that class and in this case i just can control the maximum rate not minimum rate and it depend on the number of users that use of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you right, you trying to create 70000 child classes like that (1:1 - 1:70000), am I right?
if I am right, have you tried to add some intermediate classes (for example 1:1 - 1:9999, 2:1 -2:9999, etc.) ?
You may need to create more complex tree... 
For example you could classify traffic by subnets at first and by ip at the leaf classes.

Comment: yes you are right . before your answer i didn't know about this kind of classes ( 2:1 - 2:9999) and didn't know that can have this type of class in my scenario. i added it and it worked, very very tank you for your help

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read [this](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html) few times before doing something.